# Populate userform with records from current row

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I have a userform with several textboxes, radio buttons, dropdowns, etc. When a user creates a new entry, the data is saved on the Data sheet, with one record occupying one row. Now I want to be able to click an "edit" button in column A which allows to load the userform preloaded with the data from this row.

The issue is that when the form is loaded, the initialization macro resets all form fields to "", and I havent figured out how to tell VBA to load the calling row's data.

Any suggestions on how to go about this?

---

Here the code I have so far:
call the userform when the NEW ENTRY button is clicked

```
Sub call_userform()

Details.Show

End Sub
```

when the userform is initialized:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

IC_logo.BackColor = RGB(81, 81, 73) ' ash grey

'Empty all fields
status.Value = "Open"
serial = Evaluate("randbetween(10000,30000)")
priority.Value = ""
created_on.Value = Format(Date, "dd/mm/yyyy")
created_by.Value = ""
department.Value = ""
floor.Value = ""
area.Value = ""
subarea.Value = ""
details.Value = ""
fu_name.Value = ""
fu_department = ""

Me.status.RowSource = "lst_status"              'Fill Status
Me.priority.RowSource = "lst_priority"          'Fill Priorities
created_by = Sheets("Settings").Range("B24")    'Fill Created By with Logon Username
department = Sheets("Settings").Range("B25")    'Fill Created By with Logon Department
Me.floor.RowSource = "lst_floor"                'Fill Floor
Me.area.RowSource = "lst_area"                  'Fill Area
Me.subarea.RowSource = "lst_subarea"            'Fill Subarea

'Set follow up to construction company as per default
'fu_2.Value = True

'Set Focus on NameTextBox
priority.SetFocus

End Sub
```

when the SAVE button is clicked

```
Private Sub btn_save_Click()
Dim emptyRow As Long

'Activate Data sheet
Sheets("Data").Activate

'Determine emptyRow
emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("B:B")) + 1

'Transfer information
Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = serial.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value = created_on.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 5).Value = created_by.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 6).Value = priority.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 7).Value = floor.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 8).Value = area.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 9).Value = subarea.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 10).Value = details.Value

If fu_1.Value = True Then
    Cells(emptyRow, 11).Value = fu_1.Caption
End If
If fu_2.Value = True Then
    Cells(emptyRow, 11).Value = fu_2.Caption
End If
If fu_3.Value = True Then
    Cells(emptyRow, 11).Value = fu_3.Caption
End If
If fu_4.Value = True Then
    Cells(emptyRow, 11).Value = fu_4.Caption
End If

If fu_name.Value > 0 Or fu_department.Value > 0 Then
    Cells(emptyRow, 12).Value = fu_name.Value & " " & fu_department.Value
End If

Cells(emptyRow, 13).Value = status.Value

End Sub
```

As mentioned, the problem now is how do I load the userform with the data of the current row? Would that still be via `details.show` ?

Comment: Do you have only one button? Can you post the code you have so far? If you want to load the Textboxes when opening the Form, use the `UserForm_Activate()` Sub

Comment: The "load" code is the opposite of the "save" code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd go like follows:

- use `Tag` property of the `UserForm` object to store a "calling parameter" that will tell UserForm whether to run an `InitializeValues()` Sub or a `FillValues()` one
- use `UserForm_Activate` event handler to have UserForm decide which action is to be taken

so, assuming you attach an `Edit()` sub to your sheet "edit" buttons, the former would be

```
Sub Edit()
    With UserForm3
        .Tag = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Row '<~~ tell the UserForm there's something to bring in so that it'll fill controls from the sheet instead of initializing them
        .Show
        .Tag = "" '<~~ bring Tag property back to its "null" value
    End With
    Unload UserForm3
End Sub
```

then in you UserForm code pane place this

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    If Me.Tag = "" Then '<~~ if there's no info from Tag property...
        InitializeValues '<~~ ... then Initialize controls values
    Else
        FillValues '<~~ ...otherwise fill controls with sheet values
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub InitializeValues()
    With Me
        .ComboBox1.RowSource = "initRange"
        .serial.Value = "actText1"
        .created_on.Value = "actText2"
        .created_by.Value = "actText3"
        ' and so on...
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub FillValues()
    With Me
        .serial.Value = Cells(.Tag, 2).Value
        .created_on.Value = Cells(.Tag, 4).Value
        .created_by.Value = Cells(.Tag, 5).Value
        '.. and so on
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have one Button on your sheet to call the form, then just use something like this:

```
me.TextBox1.value = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 2).Value 'ActiveCell.Row returns the row number of the current cell
```

So the only command the button has is `UserForm1.Show`

Comment: yes, but HOW do i call this? If the form is opened via `userform.show` then it will automatically load the code in sub userform_initialize.... How can I load the empty form and populate the content?

Comment: I wouldn't use userform_initialize to load data, use userform_activate instead.

Comment: let me be clear. When I use `userform.show` the code stored in sub userform_initialize is executed automatically. HOW do I call the userform in order to trigger the userform_activate sub? would that be `userform.activate` ?

Comment: for me the userform_activate sub gets triggered when i open the form with userform.show

Comment: then how does the userform_initialize get triggered? Respectively, how can I tell VBA to load an empty form when the NEW ENTRY button is clicked, but load a populated form when the "EDIT" button in the active rows is clicked?

Comment: You can define a global variable inside the form codemodule, set different values when pressing the buttons and check the value in userform_initialize

Answer (score 0):

You can write a sub like `loadDataIntoForm(rowNum As Long)` that fills the fields of the form to your liking and put it into the code of the userform.
e.g.

```
Public Sub loadDataIntoForm(rowNum As Long)
    me.somecontrol.Value = Sheets("Data").cells(rowNum,1).Value
    '...
End Sub
```

Then if the edit button is clicked execute

```
Details.loadDataIntoForm(rowNum) 'where rowNum is something like ActiveCell.Row. This calls UserForm_Initialize and THEN loadDataIntoForm
Details.Show 'UserForm_Initialize won't get executed again
```

`UserForm_Initialize` is executed before `loadDataIntoForm` is so the fields get cleared first by the `UserForm_Initialize` function and then re-populated by `loadDataIntoForm`. To be sure you could also load the form first

```
Load Details
Details.loadDataIntoForm(ActiveCell.Row)
Details.Show
```

So you can be sure `UserForm_Initialize` is not called after `loadDataIntoForm`.

To get a sense of what is called when you can go through the code line by line using F8.

---

edit: A nicer way would probably be to write two subs, one for initializing the form for an edit (populate the fields) and one for initializing the form for a new record (clear the fields)

It could look something like

```
Public Sub ShowNew()
    'clear all the controls
    me.Show
End Sub

Public Sub ShowEdit(rowNum As Long)
    'populate the controls
    me.Show
End Sub
```

Then instead of using `Details.Show` use `Details.ShowNew` and `Details.ShowNew(rowNum)`

Comment: sorry, you completely lost me. where do I put what and which sub do I call when the button in the row is clicked?

Comment: to clarify, I have 2 buttons on the sheet. One to create a "NEW ENTRY", which means I need the form to be loaded without any values as I have defined it in the userform_initialize sub, and then another button for "EDIT ENTRY" where I want the form to load with values from the active row. How do I do this and what subs should I use?

Comment: @Armitage2k I edited my post for more clarity (hopefully)