# Create a userform in VBA for data entry of new record into a table

Tags: excel, vba, userform

Editing the form controls in VBA seems quite easy, however I am new to creating userforms and have no idea how to create the corresponding macro to actually make the form work.

I have tried searching the web, but cannot find any 'simple' codes for me to expand upon.

I want my form to add a new record to my named client table, the headers of the table are: Name, Address, Telephone, Mobile and Email.

Any starting points would be incredibly appreciated.

Comment: Create  an Excel Userform <https://www.contextures.com/xlUserForm01.html> shall help you...

Comment: There are relevant questions on here that may help you, see this one for example : https://stackoverflow.com/q/37560187/4961700

Comment: What is the named client table? What DB are you using? Do you have any code that allows adding a new record with some hardcoded values? Also why you choose Excel, but not Access?